# How to fix 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value that is not equal to the supplied origin on Webview Android?

Tags: php, ajax, webview, cors

So I have a Webview on my Android App. In the HTML page, I have an ajax call that gets a value from my own hosted php in a domain, whenever a user clicks/touches the button.

Ajax Call in WebView/HTML File:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/test/test.php", //url of php file
crossDomain: true,
}).done(function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

In my php file, I have the following code:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: file:///android_asset/www/index.html');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');

echo "Hello World";

?>
```

Here, I ran into a CORS issue, whereby it's telling me my 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'file:///android_asset/www/index.html' that is not equal to the supplied origin. What should the value be? Also, if I have multiple devices using the same php file, how do I make it dynamic?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');

 echo "Hello World";
?>
```

Comment: that's weird, it gives me a "Cannot use wildcard (*)" when I tried to use the * previously. Now it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: glad to help you